# C++ signal names passed from program parameters

Tags: c++, type-conversion, signals

So I've got this problem where I want to call my program with parameter for main function (let's say I called it like this: *program SIGQUIT*) and pass this parameter to kill() and signal() functions in the code.

The question I'm kindly asking is: how do I get integer signal number from char type argv[2] which contains "SIGQUIT"?

Comment: Do note that n.m.'s answer silently assumes that you are using `bash` as your shell - it won't work with `dash` or even `zsh` because of different format of the output of `kill -l`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just build a lookup table with the string and the corresponding `int`? If you only need the signals defined on your system, you will need something like:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // lookup table
    std::map<std::string, int> lookup_table;
#define ADD_SIGNAL(X)    lookup_table.insert(std::make_pair(#X,X));
    // standard signals
    ADD_SIGNAL(SIGABRT);
    ADD_SIGNAL(SIGFPE);
    ADD_SIGNAL(SIGILL);
    ADD_SIGNAL(SIGINT);
    ADD_SIGNAL(SIGSEGV);
    ADD_SIGNAL(SIGTERM);

    // implementation specific signals
#ifdef SIGKILL
    ADD_SIGNAL(SIGKILL);
#endif
#ifdef SIGSTOP
    ADD_SIGNAL(SIGSTOP);
#endif
    // ...

#undef ADD_SIGNAL

    assert(argc > 1 && "No signal");
    std::string sig = argv[1];

    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = lookup_table.find(sig);
    if(it != lookup_table.end())
        std::cout << "Signal " << it->first << ": " << it-> second << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Unknown signal " << sig << std::endl;
}
```

It is a bit long to write up all the signals, you can use this command line (assuming POSIX) to generate them:

```
 kill -l  | sed 's/[0-9]*)//g'
          | grep -v "[+-]"  
          | xargs -n1 echo 
          | awk '{ print "#ifdef " $0 "\n\tADD_SIGNAL(" $0 ")\n#endif" }'
```